# How can I drop multiple columns in DB2 on AIX?

Tags: sql, db2

What is the syntax to drop multiple columns in DB2?  I tried this:

```
ALTER TABLE work_item DROP COLUMN (TRANSACTION_TYPE, REQUEST_TYPE, LOCATION_CODE, ROLE_ID, SUBMITTED_BY);
```

But it didn't work.  I am running on AIX (from what I read, it looks like maybe you cannot drop columns at all on platforms other than AIX).

If I drop the columns one by one, it seems to work, but after the first three, I need to `REORG` the table.  I want to do this in one fell swoop, with no REORG.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following works for me on DB2 9.5 on Windows, but it should work on earlier versions on AIX as well:

```
ALTER TABLE MYSCHEMA.ABC
DROP COLUMN B
DROP COLUMN C
```

[Here's the documentation on the ALTER TABLE command](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000888.html)

Comment: pkaeding: Your welcome. DB2 is my favourite database system, it's a shame that I don't get to work with it a lot lately as my current company uses Oracle.